# Is there a way to access details of all instances from a single instance during application upgrade?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm working on a POC to clear instance level custom health events reported by each instance of the service (Service deployed on 3 instances currently). **I'm clearing the reports on start of an application upgrade**.

Now the problem is in case there is any "Error" event reported by any or all of the instances, while doing an application upgrade, the first instance gets updated (reports also get cleared) but since the other two are still in Error state, SF rolls back the upgrade.

One option for me is to do an Unmonitored Force upgrade. But just want to know if there is any way that I can access the other two instances' data, like from **NodeContext**? If there is, I would like to try to clear the custom error health events from other instances as well while upgrading the first instance.

Thank you!

Comment: your question is not clear. What do you mean by "I'm clearing the reports on start of an application upgrade."? Also what exactly you do when you say "upgrade"?

Comment: I'm clearing out the custom health events that are reported by the service on an application upgrade, like a configuration version upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're misusing the health model. An error health state is *supposed to* stop a rolling upgrade. If you simply clear error health states before starting an upgrade, then there's really no point in reporting the error health state in the first place.

> Now the problem is in case there is any "Error" event reported by any or all of the instances, while doing an application upgrade, the first instance gets updated (reports also get cleared) but since the other two are still in Error state, SF rolls back the upgrade.

Yes, this is an important feature of Service Fabric. The system is doing exactly what it's supposed to do: it rolls back your upgrade because you reported an error.

From Service Fabric's point of view, an error state is severe enough that the system won't touch your service because that could lead to further catastrophic problems, like data loss. That means upgrades (application and system) will halt and rollback if you've configured it that way.

An example of using the health system to your advantage would be to have some code that evaluates the functionality of a service and reports health based on that. This way, when someone changes service code and rolls out an upgrade, the service's functionality is evaluated and if something's not working properly, an error health state is reported which stops the upgrade and rolls it back for you. That evaluation code can even be in a separate service, called a "watch dog" which can be as simple as pinging one of your service's endpoint and making sure the response is OK.

I highly recommend reading over the health model documentation carefully to get a feel for how it all works, then experimenting a bit to see what works for your specific problem domain. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-health-introduction